# CakePHP-3 config to show executed query at bottom

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I enabled debug mode in app.php but could not able see queries and there execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation on logging queries:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging

And the configuration options for the connection:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#configuration

You will be able to see logged queries in the `tmp/logs/debug.log` file inside your application.

You can use `tail -f debug.log` in a terminal window to get a live feedback of the queries being executed.

Answer (score 0):

When enable debugging, you should use the debugkit which is provided by cake. Just add this to the composer-file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.*"
    }
}
```

(And turn the "debug" in app.php to true)